# Can multiple subdomains affect SEO results?

Tags: seo, domains, url

The question is there is one site named: `www.example.com`.

But the issue with site is it can open after entering whatever instead of `www.`
e.g.:

- `xxx.example.com`
- `john.example.com`
- `micky.example.com`

Is this a fault in the site? Can this affect SEO results?

Comment: What happens when a user visits `john.example.com`?   Do they see the same content as when they visit the `www`?  Do they get a redirect?  Do they get an error?

Comment: page goes to www.example.com

Comment: "goes to" as in "redirects to" or "shows the content at the alternate URL"?

Comment: yes that means it redirects to the www.example.com

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it may affect if the sub-domains point to same content pages. All you need to do is use 301 re-direct and canonical  here is the link:  [When to use canonical? Prepaid products of different values](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60069/when-to-use-canonical-prepaid-products-of-different-values)

Comment: but where to use canonical. it goes to home page after putting any digit, character instead of www

Comment: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en

Comment: There is no harm in doing a 301 redirect from any sub-domain to the site. Nothing else needs to be done. Google will understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Setting up DNS to allow any subdomain is known as [wildcard subdomains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wildcard_DNS_record).   Allowing any subdomain through this mechanism is fine for SEO as long as they redirect.   My domains are all set up this way.

Since you say you have a redirect in place that will take users to the canonical `www` subdomain, there will be no SEO problems.   It would be an SEO problem to duplicate the same site on every subdomain such that Googlebot would then find multiple copies of the site and lots of duplicate content.